# cube completion

Tags: pattern, dice

Choose the correct option. I can only eliminate first one. Dunno why but 2,3 and 4 seems correct to me. Please correct me if I'm wrong[image]

Comment: 1, 3 and 4 are wrong obviously because the circles aren't side-by-side. 2 works fine of course

Answer (score 6):

Case 1: Those circles in choices 1, 3 & 4 are in a horizontal line

> Well yeah clearly it would be neither of those. On the other hand, it could be an error in drawing... it would be choice 2 in that case.

Case 2: Pretend that they are in a diagonal line, somehow.

> The triangles in choice 3 only have 1 side that is parallel to an edge of the cube. Using this as a guide, we see that the triangles should be pointing at a lone circle. In choice 3, they point to a square. 
>  Choice 4 on the other hand... I mean, I swear those symbols are in a straight vertical/horizontal line! If we don't know, choice 4 *could* be true... Overall, since I don't see a reason why it can't be choice 2, I would just pick choice 2 and move on to a question with better drawn diagrams man :/